# Firebase SDK does not respond randomly

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I've been working on a React app which uses Firebase as a backend for some time now.

Lately, I'm experiencing a very weird bug. Randomly, the Firebase SDK just doesn't respond to any function I call when loading the app.

The app initializes with firebase.auth.onAuthStateChanged() to check whether a user is logged in. This function is never called. When I try to access the Firestore, no callback is fired. When I enable logging, not one line is logged. It just doesn't do anything anymore. Refreshing the page does not solve the issue. Clearing localStorage, cookies, indexedDb doesn't do anything either.

Sometimes, it just starts to work after a while. But most of the time, only force quitting the browser or visiting the website in incognito mode fixes the issue.

Did anyone experience this issue? Or has any clue where to start looking? It's hard to reproduce, but when it happens, there's pretty much nothing I seem to be able to do in JavaScript to fix it. It also doesn't seem to happen when I run the app whilst developing (localhost).

To me, it seems the Firebase backend is not reachable in some way, blocking the whole SDK.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: What firebase sdk version are you using ?

Some were broken with react (native)

Comment: @rphlmr 7.6.0; but I also tried with the latest version and unfortunately this didn’t make any difference

Comment: Something  that could happen is that your React component re render before onAuthStateChanged responds and cancel the request. It could explain the random thing. But there is a lot of other reason :D. Do you have some code around onAuthStateChanged ? Maybe something can help

Comment: Could you share your code where you are calling `onAuthStateChanged`?